# Update a table (not the model ) in post hook dbt

Tags: dbt

I have a use case to update control table with the dates that are being loaded into the model(main) table. I am using post hook to achieve this like below

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = "incremental" ,
        transient  = "true" ,
        query_tag = "adapter_merge",
        post_hook = """
       update dbt_ctl set load_dt = (select max(load_dt) from {{this}}
        """
    )
}}
```

But when I run the model, its not adding db.schema qualifier and throwing an error that table doesn't exist. table exists and has access to the dbt role.
I could update model in post hook but I need to update another control table and not the model.
I even tried as macro but didn't work.
Appreciate any help.

db:Snowflake